# Multiple types of versions for a single topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

It would be helpful if topics supported multiple versions. e.g. for [Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring-mvc/topics), it would be fantastic if we could tie a topic or example to both the version of Spring MVC (e.g. `4.2.x`), and *also* to the version of the servlet spec that the example or topic requires (e.g. `Servlet Spec 2.5`). These are fairly tightly coupled, but *not* perfectly so, and it would be fantastic if we could specify both.

I'm not sure what this would look like - possibly adding multiple version sections? Or multiple tables to a single version section?